# Can I Ready an action to do something I'm not currently capable of doing?

Tags: dnd-5e, readied-action

Suppose I'm not currently holding a sword, but my ally is going to toss one to me on their next turn. Can I ready an action to attack with the sword that I'm not yet in possession of, with a trigger of "when I acquire a sword"?

A similar situation arises with spells that grant the ability to perform new actions, such as [*dragon's breath*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dragons-breath). Can I ask my wizard ally to cast this spell on me and then ready an action to breathe fire with a trigger of "when I have *dragon's breath* cast on me"?

In general, the question is: **if I am not currently capable of taking a certain action, can I still ready that action if I expect to *become* capable of it some time in the next round?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there something in the rules that leads to the belief that this may *not* be possible?

Comment: @HeyICanChan It seems like it should be possible, but I'm not certain whether or not readying an action implies that you are doing something on your turn to get that action ready, such as shifting into an attack stance with your sword (which would obviously require a sword).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## Yes you can Ready an action you currently cannot do

The rules for Readying say:

> First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose **the action you will take** in response to that trigger, or you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

Readying doesn't involve doing anything at all at the time that you Ready. All you have to do is choose "the action you **will** take". Decide a trigger and decide a future action, there are no other requirements other than that.<sup>1</sup>

Or, as @RyanThompson says in a comment below:

> The key idea is that the ready action means you're doing nothing now and maybe doing something later, and you can always do nothing right now.

Thus, there is no rules or logical reason why you cannot ready an action "to attack with a sword when a receive it from my ally" or "breath fire once my ally casts *dragon's breath* on me".

Of course if the thing or ability your action depends on fails to get to you before your next turn you have wasted your action, so this is even riskier than a normal Readied action.

#### Exception: You cannot Ready a spell you cannot cast

Readying a spell requires you to start casting that spell as part of the Ready action.

> When you ready a spell, you cast it as normal but hold its energy...

If you do not meet the requirement to start casting spells (or that spell in particular) then you cannot Ready a spell. It is good to note that you don't have to choose a target or even have one in range to start casting the spell.

---

<sup>1 - You *can* describe the Ready mechanic ***narratively*** as taking some preparatory action (holding a sword above your head ready to strike, getting into a sprinter position to get ready to move, etc.) in your game, but that is not dictated or even implied by the ***rules***. The rules simply state the mechanics of taking the action and let the DM and players find a narrative that work with it. Following the rules and creating a compelling logical narrative can sometimes be at odds with each other and nothing in the game says that they have to get along all the time.
It is up to the DM/table to decide where to draw that line and where and how much to tweak rules they see as crossing it. Regardless, the rules say what they say.</sup>

Comment: I think this answers the question most directly. The key idea is that the ready action means you're doing nothing now and maybe doing something later, and you can always do nothing right now.

Comment: I just thought of one important caveat that kind of contradicts my previous comment: I believe readying an action still requires you to use your action on your turn, so mechanically, you can't do it if you're unable to take actions, even if readying an action doesn't mean you're doing anything on your turn. For example, if you're paralyzed, you can't ready an attack for when you become un-paralyzed.

Comment: @RyanThompson good point. You always have to meet the prereqs for the Ready action. I'll update my answer to include the caveat.

Answer (score 28):

#### Yes, you can ready actions you are not currently capable of performing*

(*Well, you can't ready a spell that you were not capable of casting, but I don't know how that would come up.)

What are the requirements for readying? (emphasis mine)

> First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose the action you **will take** in response to that trigger, or you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

and

> When the trigger occurs, you can either take your reaction right after the trigger finishes or ignore the trigger. Remember that you can take only one reaction per round.

Examples include "If the cultist steps on the trapdoor, I'll pull the lever that opens it," and "If the goblin steps next to me, I move away."

---

It's simple enough to imagine a readied action to the effect of "If I receive a sword from my buddy Fighter McFighterson, then I attack the goblin." (Though, you may get some guff from your DM about interacting with an object off turn. Personally, I'd allow it.), or "If someone casts dragonbreath on me, I use it on the toothpick golems.".

---

Note 1 : Readying spells requires you to actually "cast" the spell and hold it until your trigger. That's why, if for some reason you received a spell slot, you couldn't then react to that by casting a spell.

Note 2 : Don't forget that if you use one of these triggers dependent on someone else, and the thing doesn't happen, you've wasted your action.

Comment: I have a hard time thinking that the definition of Ready allows you to pick actions that are not allowed at the time of your Ready action. At the time of declaration you have a list of actions you can perform until your list is ammended by said spell later you would not have the action available to include with your Ready declaration. I could be wrong, of course, but that is how I read the intent of the Ready action.

Comment: @Slagmoth a perfectly reasonable interpretation. I encourage you to put up your own answer to that effect ^_^. Though, how do you feel about readying actions with abilities that no longer are available at the time of your trigger? What if dragonsbreath had been dispelled and you'd readied it to use on the toothpick golem?

Comment: @Slagmoth Why not?  You can't attack the goblin that is behind the door (because they are behind the door), but you can ready an action to do so when you are able. You also can Ready a spell when there aren't any valid targets in range. Why would you think that you can't ready an action to, for example, attack with a sword you are about to receive?

Comment: You may want to emphasize the "will take" part of your first quote. Readying doesn't involve doing anything, only declaring what you *will do* when your trigger occurs.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Because Attack is on the list of actions that you can take at the time of your declaration. Just like Move etc. And to your example goodguy5, at the time I made the declaration I was able to Breathe Fire so after it was dispelled it was *interrupted* for lack of a better word. Again, that is just my interpretation of how a turn based system would work.

Comment: Although, I suppose it is just an action... just smells weird to think about it that way.

Comment: (Don't know how it would come up example):  "I ready to cast the spell Shield as soon as Bob puts the ring of spell storing on my finger".  Can't do that because you have to cast the spell to ready it.  (Why Bob would be holding it is a mystery, however, that won't by itself remove attunement.)

Comment: @Slagmoth How I would interpret it is that the "action" you are performing with Ready is that you are declaring an _intent_ to perform an action later when a defined set of circumstances arise, and it's not until the time when those circumstances take place that you must check to see if you can perform said action.

Comment: @ReginaldBlue that example can't be readied, but the result would work without ready. Shield can only be cast as a reaction to being hit with an attack. You can't cast it without a triggering attack (or Magic Missile). But you can instead use your reaction to cast it IF you are attacked AFTER the ring is put on your finger.

Comment: i suppose it could matter in the case "I Cast fireball once the cleric dispels feeblemind on me"

Comment: @Mouhgouda as much as I like that idea (and would probably allow it), I don't think it's allowed by RAW... or even RAI.

Answer (score 13):

## Yes.  The player can state any action for the character to ready.  It is incumbent on the DM to narrate what happens if the action is impossible.

**TL;DR** This comes back to: the player states what the character does; the GM narrates the result.

[Ready an action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Ready):

> First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger, or you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

Having *dragonbreath* cast on you is a perceivable circumstance.  Attempting to breathe fire on enemies is an action you will take in response to the trigger.  This satisfies the player part of how [adventuring works](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/adventuring):

> 1. The DM describes the environment.
> 2. The players describe what they want to do.
> 3. The DM narrates the results of their actions.

### Narrative Example

GM: "It's the rogue's turn"

Wizard Player: "My wizard exclaims to the rogue, 'Get ready to breathe fire!'"

Rogue Player: "My rogue nods knowingly to the wizard, and readies their action to breathe fire on the goblins as soon as the wizard casts dragon breath on him."

DM: "The party rogue takes a deep breath and glares angrily at the goblins as he begins to turn red in the face. It's the wizard's turn."

Wizard Player:  "I cast dragon breath on the rogue."

DM: "You touch the rogue as you finish casting dragon breath.  Our crimson faced rogue does his best dragon impression and breathes fire on the goblins.  Roll for damage."

Comment: Minor point about the example: When the trigger happens, the rogue should have the chance to decide whether to do the readied action or not.